# How can i load the code to flash through TWI?

Tags: i2c, atmega, atmelstudio

I have a board with atmega328p on it and my question is how can i download the code in to the flash through TWI ?

Comment: You could study how serial bootloaders (like Optiboot) work and then adapt them to use TWI instead of the UART and the communication method.  It's unlikely anyone here will write the whole bootloader for you.  This is probably more trouble than it's worth though, are you sure your board doesn't give access to the AVR's ISP pins so you can just program it with a normal programmer?  How are you going to program a bootloader onto the AVR in the first place?

Comment: Well i can make a bootloader for AVR but if i have no bootloader in the device how can i download the code of my bootloader to the device ?